# Use of "Thanks a million"

Tags: connotation

Is it true that "thanks a million" is usually used with a slightly negative connotation? 
I often use it to end friendly emails. But I have seen somewhere that it has a negative connotation as in this example "You've finished my chocolates, thanks a million!" 
I hope people didn't get offended when I used it in emails, my intention was positive...

Comment: Welcome to  English Language & Usage. You might wish to distinguish between written and spoken when asking about this phrase. In the example you give, "thanks a million" might be a positive statement said to one who removed the temptation of chocolates. There is no telling without context.

Answer (score 1):

***[Thanks a million](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thanks_a_million)*** is just an idiomatic expression meaning "thank you very much".

It can be used sarcastically as any other form of saying "thank you", but I don't think it has a special negative connotation in itself.